# How can I create previous and next buttons for a multiple div form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, division

[image]

I have a form that has several "pages" with each "page" being a container holding some content.

I would like to have previous and next buttons following these rules:

- Clicking the next button should progress forward through the form's pages until the last page and stop
- Clicking the previous button should progress backwards through the form until the first page and stop.

[Here is the example of similar functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/1khczygj/) except it does't follow the rules above because hitting next on the last page cycles back to the first and vice versa.

#### Here is what I have tried so far:

`JS`

```
$('.box button').click(function() {
    
    $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });
    
    var t=$(this);
    t.parent().animate({
         left: '-50%'
     }, 500);
 
     if (t.parent().next().size() > 0) {
         t.parent().next().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     } else {
         t.parent().prevAll().last().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     }
});
```

Comment: Sorrt this is my First time using StackOverflow. i cant attach the jsfiddle link on my post. the link is here: https://jsfiddle.net/1khczygj/

Comment: simple [ type word here ]( paste link here )

Comment: I think its better to use (I tried and not working) instead of (I want) .. your code and demo dose not have any next or prev arrows .. so how can we help??

Comment: Sorry this post is a mess. i have to delete this post and re-post thanks for the advice.

Comment: no dont delete and repost just edit this one

Comment: I have edited your question to better relay your issue. This should help with the downvotes. But more importantly, clear and concise questions are more likely to be helpful for others searching for similar issues in the future. One thing that is still missing. When asking such a question, you should specifically state how your attempt did not function as expected which will greatly help others understand how to help. Fell free to add that bit above to round out your question :)

Comment: BTW, just me, but I'd switch the placement of your next and back buttons. Typically the back button would be on the left. That's where I'd expect it to be at least.

Comment: Thanks!~DelightedD0D i am stilling learning how to post a good question instead a mess question XD. thanks for you formation. i have learnt a lot!.

Comment: Yes i was totally mis-uses the post here. i should have post a 'How to improved post' instead of a 'what do i want post'. Thanks for you advise. @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is one method that will achieve this (note that this could be simplified a good bit but doing so here would make it more difficult to understand for new programers):

```js
$('.previous').click(function () {
    var cur = $('.form-panel').index($('.form-panel.active'));
    if (cur!=0) {
        $('.form-panel').removeClass('active');
        $('.form-panel').eq(cur-1).addClass('active');
    }
});
$('.next').click(function () {
    var cur = $('.form-panel').index($('.form-panel.active'));
    if (cur!=$('.form-panel').length-1) {
        $('.form-panel').removeClass('active');
        $('.form-panel').eq(cur+1).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.form-panel:not(.active) {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-panel active">Panel one content here</div>
<div class="form-panel">Panel two content here</div>
<div class="form-panel">Panel three content here</div>
<div class="form-panel">Panel four content here</div>
<div class="form-panel">Panel five content here</div>
<div class="form-panel">Panel six content here</div>
<br>
<button class="previous">Previous</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

If you require animations, this method can easily be modified to include them.

Comment: Thanks!!!! you help me a lot. this is the excectly effect that i want to implement. i was trying make a new demo for re-editing this post. but you have answer excetly i want. so i think i should accept your answer as perfect answer. BTW i am still trying to understand how to format posting on StackOverFlow. thanks for your answer!

Comment: Happy to help, Regarding your comment about formatting posts, when you ask a question, there is a little question mark icon, if you click that it'll open a dropdown that will show you the available formatting options [see this image](http://i.imgur.com/8m790j6.png)